# "Bad Allocation" Error importing Large OSM into QGIS and QuickOSM

Tags: qgis, quickosm, unity3d

I am trying to build a map of the state of Florida for a flight simulator in Unity. I am new to the GIS world.

I have downloaded QGIS, ArcGIS, City Engine, and Unity to do this.

I downloaded my files from the OpenStreetMap website susadary links. The German one.

I have converted the osm.pbf to a OSM file
now when I try to upload this file into QuickOSM, it runs out my memory and says bad allocation and nothing shows up.

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? Why do you want to convert the PBF file to an OSM file? QGIS reads PBF.

Comment: I am currently using QGIS 3.10. I thought converting the osm.pbf to osm would be better but like I said, I am still new to GIS and am trying to learn fast.

Comment: Can you add these information in your question, not as comment. Can you also add whick kind of keys do you want? Or do you want a small subset, or a lot of them?